# Would this custom Legerdemain feat have any serious balance issues?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, balance, homebrew-review

From the dictionary:

> Legerdemain: skillful use of one's hands when performing conjuring
>   tricks.

In 5th Edition the Arcane Trickster Rogue subclass is provided with *Mage Hand Legerdemain.* This expands Mage Hand to be able to use thieves' tools, pick pocket, and other things typically attributable to the use of a "Sleight of Hand" check.

> **Mage Hand Legerdemain**
>
> Starting at 3rd level, when you cast mage hand, you can make the spectral hand invisible, and you can perform the following additional tasks with it:
>
> - You can stow one object the hand is holding in a container worn or
>     carried by another creature.
> - You can retrieve an object in a container worn or carried by another 
>     creature.
> - You can use thieves’ tools to pick locks and disarm traps at range.
>
> You can perform one of these tasks without being noticed by a creature if you succeed on a Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check contested by the creature’s Wisdom (Perception) check.
>
> In addition, you can use the bonus action granted by your Cunning Action to control the hand.

My bard from the start was a "fast talking street hustler" with extra proficiency in Sleight of Hand and Deception. I generally use this combination for introducing myself with one hand and pick-pocketing with the other, but I recently discovered that Arcane Tricksters get the ability to do this with Mage Hand.  That seems really fun but not really worth slowing my Bard progression for.

Would a custom feat that reads as follows have any serious game breaking repercussions?

> **Legerdemain**
>
> *Prerequisite: The Mage Hand cantrip*
>
> Your mastery over the illusional hand has granted you:
>
> - Increase your Dexterity score by 1, to a maximum of 20.
> - You can use your Mage Hand without being noticed by a creature if you succeed on a Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check contested by the creature’s Wisdom (Perception) check.
> - You can control your existing Mage Hand as a bonus action.

Comment: Do you have anyone else in the group wanting to steal or perform slight of hand tricks? The answer changes dramatically imho as you can more easily put the other person in the shade by being useful in way more situations.

Answer (score 6):

### Unlikely to be a problem.

This is (arguably) exactly for what feats are for. You're adding a new mechanic to your character.

What are the main considerations when creating a new (anything, but in this case) feat?

1. Does this "step on the toes" of another player?

   - Unless there is an Arcane Trickster, probably not.
2. Is this overpowered, i.e.- will it always get picked? (*cough* Lucky *cough*)

   - Not everyone can even take it. Personally, I doubt I would.
3. Is this fun / does this add anything?

   - This seems like something you've been aiming for and have found a way to be a sneaky conman.
4. Does this detract anything from the game?

   - It's fairly safe to say that the ability itself isn't "bad" for the game, as it's already in the game.

**Things to consider:**

- Class abilities as feats is potentially dangerous.
- There is already a precedent with Magic Initiate and Martial Adept, though weaker than their base form
- I would call it "Maged Legerdemain"

Comment: How about "arcane legerdemain" for a name? :)  (Bards are arcane casters ...)

Comment: It is weaker then the tricksters ability, apears balanced

Comment: I can't resist the urge to suggest calling it "Handy Legerdemain" instead.